# How to make tabs from jquery-ui to reorder if in rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

If I have very many tabs in tabs widget from jquery-ui, then tabs go in several rows. Unfortunately, if I select first tab, it remains in first row, visually detached from content it denotes.

Below "Mobility" tab is selected.

[image]

Is it possible to make rows of tabs reorder so the row, containing selected tab, goes down?

Comment: So, you want to change the order of the tabs depending on what tab the user has clicked on? That sounds like a terrible user experience.

I'd suggest that you find a better way to display your data such as an accordion.

Comment: I saw reordering of tabs in some real UIs

Answer (score 2):

On selecting the tab you can place that tab at the last. That way it wont look detached

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
select: function(event, ui) {
    $(ui.tab).parents('li').insertAfter($('#tabs ul li:last')); //insert after last tab      
}       
});
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/z6CEq/

Comment: Yes, but this will confuse user. It would better if tabs reorder only grouped by lines.

Comment: @Dims How do you want them to reorder?

Comment: For example, if tabs were splitted into two rows, then entire row, as a whole, should go down. But if tab is 2nd within this row, it should remain second.